# Uploaded images not showing in mysql table PHP BLOB

Tags: php

Update: I have uploaded images using PHP BLOB, but they are not showing up in mysql table. Images are being moved to the destination folder but are not showing up in table. and when I fetch the images this code nothing shows up

> Code for uploading images

```
      <?php
        if (isset($_POST['add_p'])) {
            @$pn = $_POST['pname'];
            @$pp = $_POST['pprice'];
            @$pc = $_POST['pcategory'];
            @$date = date('d-m-y H:i:s');
            $img = $_FILES['img']['name'];
            $tmp_img = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_img, "uploads/$img");
            $insert = "INSERT INTO products (`p_name`, `p_price`, `img`, `p_category`, `date_added`) VALUES ('$pn', '$pp', '$img', '$pc', '$date')";
            mysqli_query($con, $insert);
      }
    ?>
    <form action="add-product.php" method="POST" class="form">                                 
      Name: <input class="inpt" type="text" name="pname">
      Price: <input class="inpt" type="text" name="pprice">
      Upload Image: <input class="inpt" type="file" name="img">
      Select Category
            <select class="inpt" name="pcategory">
                <option>Men</option>
                <option>Women</option>
                <option>Kids</option>
            </select>
      <input type="submit" name="add_p" value="Add Product">
     </form>
```

> Code for fetching images

```
     <?php 
        $get = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY p_id DESC LIMIT 0,4";
        $query = mysqli_query($con, $get);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo $id = $row['p_id'];
            echo $n = $row['p_name'];
            echo $p = $row['p_price'];
            echo $c = $row['p_category']; 
            echo $i = $row['img'];
        }
     ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` to your form to support file uploads:

```
<form action="add-product.php" method="POST" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean) for more details on encoding types for HTML forms.

Comment: Thanks, how dumb of me to miss that little part

Comment: Glad I could help! If it was the solution, don't forget to mark it as the answer!